# How to switch content between formGroupName inside formGroup

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two radio buttons in my formGroup lets say option-1, option-2. Inside formGroup let's say it is Parent , I have formGroupName lets say it is child. Depending on the selection of radio button i.e. option-1 and option-2 I need to change child content.

```
`MyForm : FormGroup;
initMyForm(){
  this.MyForm = this.fb.group({
   id= [''],
   key=[''],
   details= this.detailsone,//here I need to put detailone or 
                            //detailstwo based on selected radio button 
                             //(keyType)
})
}
get detailsone(){
 return this.fb.group({
   firstname:[''],
   lastname:['']
});
}
get detailstwo(){
 return this.fb.group({
   college:[''],
   subject:['']
});
}


<form [formGroup]="MyForm">
   <mat-radio-group formControlName='keyType'>
        <mat-radio-button value="option-1" >option-1</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="option-2" >option-2</mat-radio-button>
   </mat-radio-group>
   <div formGroupName="details">
   <div *ngIf="option-1">
      <input type='text' formControlName='firstname'>
      <input type='text' formControlName='lastname'>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="option-2">
      <input type='text' formControlName='college'>
      <input type='text' formControlName='subject'>
   </div>
   </div>
</form>`
```

Comment: why not an unique formGroup "details" with firstname,lastname,college and subject? NOTE: the "if" must be `*ngIf="MyForm.get('keyType').value=='option-1'"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use addControl() method to add a control to form group dynamically.

**Component.ts**

```
MyForm: FormGroup
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.initMyForm();
    this.keyType.valueChanges.subscribe((value) => {
      if (value === 'option1') {
        this.MyForm.removeControl('details');
        this.MyForm.addControl('details', this.detailsOne());
      } if (value === 'option2') {
        this.MyForm.removeControl('details');
        this.MyForm.addControl('details', this.detailstwo());
      }
    });
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="MyForm">
    <mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="keyType">
        <mat-radio-button value="option1">Option 1</mat-radio-button>
        <mat-radio-button value="option2">Option 2</mat-radio-button>
    </mat-radio-group>
    <div *ngIf="MyForm.get('details')" formGroupName="details">
        <div *ngIf="MyForm.get('keyType').value === 'option1'">
            <input type='text' formControlName='firstname'>
      <input type='text' formControlName='lastname'>
   </div>
   <div *ngIf="MyForm.get('keyType').value === 'option2'">
      <input type='text' formControlName='college'>
      <input type='text' formControlName='subject'>
   </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fmmekh)